# Position of an ImageBackground with resizeMode='contain' in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React-native and I've a very simple(at least i think so) problem.

I've an ImageBackground with `resizeMode='contain'`, now I would like to have the background positioned to the top of the container...

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.imageBackground} source={backgroundImage} resizeMode='contain'> 
... some content 
</ImageBackground>
```

The image is rendered in the right way, but the problem is that it is vertically centered, instead I would like to have it top aligned...

[This is an example of the result of my ImageBackground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpDW.jpg)

[This is an example of the result with the bottom added to ImageStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tRei.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the `ImageBackground` component, the image isn't vertically centered, rather it is positioned absolutely to fill the container. You can check the source [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js#L70). The reason it's appearing vertically centered is probably because of the resizeMode `contain`. To top align it, you can make user of the prop `imageStyle` that you can set to something like this:

```
<ImageBackground
    imageStyle={{
        bottom: 40 // Whatever offset you want from the bottom
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I had already seen the source, but this di not help me... 

with your solution, however, I do not get the effect of having the image aligned at the top... 

I thought that using `{ flex: 1, justifyDirection: 'flex-start' }` on the style of the `ImageBackground` it would have worked, but it was not...

Comment: `flex` won't work as it's absolutely positioned. What exactly is happening when you add a bottom offset? Can you inspect the styles, or better create a codepen reproducing your problem.

Comment: with the bottom offset the image moves upwards, but I can't find a value that will place the image at the top on every device, i'm wrong?

Comment: The default styles provided by react native already contains `top: 0`, `left: 0`, and `right: 0` so it should always appear on the top of every device.

Comment: I've added 2 image of example, with and without the bottom offset

Comment: The bottom offset is working as expected. You probably need to tweak few additional styles to get what you want. However, that can't be done in the comments. Please create a working example reproducing the issue.

Comment: this is the example https://snack.expo.io/@david92/imagebackground-example

Comment: I am having the same problem. In my case, I want to position the image at the bottom of my screen. Any solution?