# How to put ImageBackground with resizeMode set to "contain" at the top?

Tags: css, react-native, background-image

I'm currently displaying a background image on my React Native app using the following code:

```
<ImageBackground 
   source={myImage} 
   style={{ width:'100%', height:'100%' }} 
   imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'contain'}}
>
....
</ImageBackground>
```

I don't want my image to stretch and the `resizeMode: 'contain'` does perfectly this job. In this way the image won't cover all my screen but only a portion of it and this is exactly what I want to achieve.

My issue is that the image is vertical aligned at the center with the code I shown above while I would like it to stick at the top. So it should keep proportions and stick at the top. I tried to use `position:'absolute'` and `top:0` in the imageStyle property but it doesn't work.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715334/position-of-an-imagebackground-with-resizemode-contain-in-react-native) which apparently explain my same problem but it doesn't provide a solution to my issue.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: did you use `resizeMode` as `ImageBackground` props ?

Comment: @HardikVirani I just tried. The image is resized good as well, so I see no difference in the outcome using resizeMode as a props or as a style property. Either way the positioning is still problematic because the image is resized correctly but displayed at the center, so I would like to vertically move it to the top and stick it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { height: 0 };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
          Image.getSize(imgUrl, (srcWidth, srcHeight) => {
             const maxHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height; 
             const maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
             const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
             this.setState({ height: srcHeight * ratio})
          })
    } 

    <ImageBackground 
       source={myImage} 
       style={{ flex:1 }} 
       resizeMode= 'contain'
       imageStyle={height: this.state.height, width:Dimensions.get('window').width}
    >
    ....
    </ImageBackground>
```

`ImageBackground` as the same props as `Image` so `resizeMode` is a prop not a style

 See this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground

Comment: Well, the `resizeMode` works good in your way as well but the image is still vertically aligned at the center of the screen while I would like it to be at the top of the screen instead. The way the image is displayed with `resizeMode` is good, the problem is its positioning.

Comment: See edit, add the `height` that you want your Image to fill

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That would work indeed, proportions are kept and the image is positioned at the top, but your solution is not device-independent. On some devices the image would stick at the top but not at the right and left side.

Comment: you want the image to fill on width and the height to be "auto" is that it?

Comment: See edit, I calculate the best height for full width considering all phones

Comment: That worked! Many thanks! A side note if others come here with the same problem: the getSize function doesn't work for static images. Since my srcWidth and srcHeight are fixed (the image is only one in my case and it will stay as it is "forever"), I simply created two constants and run the code to calculate the ratio in the componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved a similar effect using static height and resizeMode cover

```
<ImageBackground 
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  imageStyle={{ height: 300 }}
  source={{ uri: entity.picture }}
  resizeMode="cover"
>
  ...
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use an Image component instead. And set the style to width: '100%';