# How to set `ImageBackground` image position in react native. Like in css `background-postion: bottom`?

Tags: react-native

So I'm setting a background image in react native but I need the position of the background image to be set to bottom. So if anyone knows how to achieve this.

I have tried adding backgroundPosition but it seems it is not supported

```
<ImageBackground
  source={require("../assets/img/bg-top.png")}
  // resizeMethod={'auto'}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: 120,
    padding: 20,
    paddingVertical: 40,
    backgroundPosition: "bottom" // not working
  }}
  imageStyle={{
    resizeMode: "cover",
    alignSelf: "flex-end"
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ color: "#D8D8D8", fontSize: 16 }}>Login</Text>
</ImageBackground>;
```

I expect the image alignment should start from the bottom rather it starts from the top

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React native provided **bottom** and **position** tag to set UI at bottom. Please replace backgroundPosition tag from image style into

**position: 'absolute',
      bottom:0**

```
 <ImageBackground
  // resizeMethod={'auto'}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: 120,
    backgroundColor:'#000',
    padding: 20,
    paddingVertical: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
  bottom:0
  }}
  imageStyle={{
    resizeMode: "cover",
    alignSelf: "flex-end"
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ color: "#D8D8D8", fontSize: 16 }}>Login</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Please check snack expo

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/bottom-ui

Answer (score 7):

The image inside ImageBackground has the default style:

```
position: 'absolute'
top: 0
bottom: 0
right: 0
left: 0
```

So, we can just remove the `top: 0` by setting

```
top: undefined
```

together we have

```
<ImageBackground
  source={require("../assets/img/bg-top.png")}
  // resizeMethod={'auto'}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: 120,
    padding: 20,
    paddingVertical: 40,
    overflow: 'hidden' // prevent image overflow the container
  }}
  imageStyle={{
    resizeMode: "cover",
    height: 200, // the image height
    top: undefined
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ color: "#D8D8D8", fontSize: 16 }}>Login</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 2):

For implementing the position of the background image I use the following code, actually I use the `ImageBackground` component as the wrapper of the entire screen:

```js
<ImageBackground
  style={styles.screenWrapper}
  imageStyle={styles.backgroundStyle}
  source={{ uri: movieDetail?.image?.medium?.url }}
>
 // children

~~~

const styles = createStyle({
  screenWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  backgroundStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: '45%',
  },
```

Finally, I reach my desire:

[image]

**Note:** *The above codes are not workable, it is just pseudo-code to convey my exact idea.*

Answer (score 0):

the backgroundPosition you know from CSS is not supported according the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground).

There is a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726116/9899193

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using **flexbox** and **percentages**:

```
function () {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  // or const {height} = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <View
      style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}
      onLayout={e => setHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: height * 0.75,
        }}
        alt="..."
        source={"..."}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The trick is you need a hard number for `height`.