# How can the image of an ImageBackground be positioned customly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `ImageBackground` over the whole screen, and I am trying to move the image, which is way bigger, to the left. When I try to position the image using `left: -100` this happens (picture below). The `ImageBackground` is moved, but moves as a whole. What I need is to move only the underlying picture, not the `View` integrated in the `ImageBackground`. How can this be achieved?

**Styling**:

```
bgImageContainer: {
    flex: 1
},
bgImage: {
    left: -100
}
```

**Code**:

```
const screenSize = {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height - StatusBar.currentHeight
    };
    return (
<ImageBackground
            source={bgImage}
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={{ ...screenSize, ...styles.bgImageContainer }}
            imageStyle={styles.bgImage}
        >
            {/* content */}
        </ImageBackground>
);
```

[image]

Comment: `background-position`...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: I agree with CBroe

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674160/5445868

Comment: It's a question regarding React Native's ImageBackground component. Therefore no, ```background-position``` does not help.

Comment: @MatteoPHRE the answers from that question are not helpful, I've already tried them before posting mine.

Comment: It's so great that nobody helps but I still get downvoted :|

Comment: I think you can handle it with margin :  first add 200px to width : ```const screenSize ={width: Dimensions.get('window').width + 100};``` and then add ```bgImage:{ margin-left: -100 }```

Comment: so if im understanding your problem correctly, you want to move just the image and not the entire container the image is in?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this work-around**

```
<View style={{ ...screenSize, ...styles.bgImageContainer }}>
    <Image source={bgImage} style={styles.bgImage} resizeMode="cover"/>
    {/* content */}
</View>
```

**Styling:**

```
bgImageContainer: {
    flex: 1
},
bgImage: {
    position:'absolute',
    width:SCREEN_WIDTH-100,
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    alignSelf:'flex-end' // if this not work make width full and add margin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with  `SafeAreaView` component

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
  
<SafeAreaView>
            <ImageBackground
            source={bgImage}
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={{ flex:1 }}
            imageStyle={styles.bgImage}
        >
            {/* content */}
        </ImageBackground>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: only aplicable on iOS