# Styling Image in React Native to show upper part

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles, stylesheet

I have an image I am displaying in my react native application. I am quite new to it and I seen to have some difficulties in regards to styling an image the way I want. I am using the resizeMode of cover and its displaying only the centre of the image and the height is cropped, I would like to display the upper-side of the image.
below is a sample code of what I have at the moment.

```
       <View style={styles.imageContentWrap}>
        <Image
         source={imageSource}
         style={styles.imageStyle}
       />
      </View>
    imageContentWrap: {
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      flex: 0.58,
    },
    imageStyle: {
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      resizeMode: 'cover',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    },
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673291/how-to-set-imagebackground-image-position-in-react-native-like-in-css-backgr/55674160 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715334/position-of-an-imagebackground-with-resizemode-contain-in-react-native/53726116#53726116

Comment: its not a duplicate because those answers do not solve my question

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: anybody found any solution yet?